# Add Partial Text Match as Criteria to a Count Unique Formula

Tags: excel, count-unique

I've been trying to add a partial text match as a criteria to the formula below, but with no success so far:

=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Sales[ClientID]=A21;IF(Sales[Operation]="Sale*";Sale[InvoiceNumber]));Sale[InvoiceNumber])>0))

The piece IF(Sales[Operation]="Sale*"; is the one that when added, always give me 0 as the result.

Here's some data:

```
Sales Table
Date         ClientID     Operation       InvoiceNumber     Total
01/01/2019   18090        Sale Adv        101010101         100
01/02/2019   20897        Sale Cash       105327892         100
01/03/2019   18090        Sample          41357398         100
01/01/2019   30456        Sale Check      43167429         100
10/04/2019   779584       Sale Cash       4326719         100
01/05/2019   30456        Refused         34162781         100
01/01/2019   90909        Sale Cash       3412679821         100
```

```
Results Table
ClientID    Purchase Frequency
779584        ???
```

Comment: You need to show some example data...

Comment: Isnumber(search())

Comment: and also demonstrate the expected output based on the sample data.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike! I've edited the question by adding data to illustrate the problem. Sorry I had it clear in my mind and thought it'd be clear to others as well.

Comment: Instead of `Sales[Operation]="Sale*"` use `AND(Sales[Operation]>"Sale",Sales[Operation]<"Salf")`

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego, would you mind explaining why "Salf" as a criteria, in this case? Appreciate your attention!

Comment: If the wildcard is not working for your and you are trying to find values like `Sale*`, then that ones are the ones between `Sale` and `Salf` on alphabetic order, so the strings on between `Sale` and `Salf`. That group are all the strings `Sale*`

Comment: I ended up using if(isnumber(search( and it worked nicely. Since the criteria is actually in PT; therefore different wordings, I decided to try another approach I had on hands and it worked. Nice to know that it's possible to play around with > followed by words and its alphabet sequence though! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I borrowed from Scot Craner, in case someone else falls into the same question:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Sales[ClientID]=A21;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sale";Sales[Operation]));Sale[InvoiceNumber]));Sale[InvoiceNumber])>0))
```

Thanks everyone!